# Angular File Upload Issue: Receiving "C:\fakepath" in Database

Tags: angular

Angular File Upload Issue: Receiving "C:\fakepath" in Database

I'm working on an Angular application where I've implemented a feature to allow users to upload image files. My goal is to send the selected image to my backend server and save it. However, I've encountered an issue: when I attempt to upload a file, I notice that the database saves a file path prefixed with "C:\fakepath", instead of the actual path or the file data.

Below is the relevant portion of my Angular code:

```
  <form [formGroup]="memberForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="fname" /><br /><br />
    <input type="text" formControlName="lname" /><br /><br />
    <input
      type="file"
      (change)="ulploadFile($event)"
      formControlName="image"
    /><br /><br />
    <button>Save</button>
  </form>
</div>

import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/Services/header.service';
import { MemberService } from 'src/app/Services/member.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private _headerService: HeaderService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _memberService: MemberService
  ) {}
  memberForm!: FormGroup;
  members: any[] = [];

  ulploadFile(event: any) {
    const file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : '';
    console.log(file);
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this._memberService.addMember(this.memberForm.value).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        alert('Employee added successfully');
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.error(err);
        alert('Error adding employee.');
      },
    });
  }

//ts file
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.memberForm = this._fb.group({
      fname: [''],
      lname: [''],
      image: [null],
    });

    this._headerService.headerTitle.next('Dashboard');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._headerService.headerTitle.next('');
  }
}

//service

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MemberService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  memberUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/member';

  addMember(data: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(this.memberUrl, data);
  }
}

getting data in API like this
[
  {
    "fname": "Test",
    "lname": "test",
    "image": "C:\\fakepath\\71Q5ZhQxgFL._AC_SX569_.jpg",
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is not related to your Angular code but rather how browsers handle file input fields. The value you see as "C:\fakepath" is a security feature implemented by web browsers to prevent websites from accessing the full path of files on the user's local machine. This behavior is intentional and cannot be changed by your Angular code.

To handle file uploads correctly, you should not rely on the file path provided by the browser. Instead, you should work with the file data itself. Here's how you can modify your code to correctly handle file uploads:

1. Update your Angular component's `ulploadFile` function to store the selected file in a property of your form control:

```js
ulploadFile(event: any) {
  const file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
  this.memberForm.get('image')?.setValue(file);
}
```

2. In your Angular component, update the `onSubmit` function to create a `FormData` object and append the file to it:

```js
onSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fname', this.memberForm.get('fname')?.value);
  formData.append('lname', this.memberForm.get('lname')?.value);
  formData.append('image', this.memberForm.get('image')?.value);

  this._memberService.addMember(formData).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
      alert('Employee added successfully');
    },
    error: (err: any) => {
      console.error(err);
      alert('Error adding employee.');
    },
  });
}
```

3. Update your backend API to handle `FormData` and store the uploaded file correctly. Ensure that your backend is configured to accept and process multipart/form-data requests.

Now, when you submit the form, it will send the file data to the server instead of the file path, and you should be able to save it correctly in your database. The "C:\fakepath" issue is a client-side security feature, and you should not rely on it for file uploads.